# xmlhttprequest open failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

```
<html>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

  var link = "http://www.utravel.com.hk/mobile-app/news-xml.php?id=3248";

 xmlhttp.open("GET",link,false);

xmlhttp.send();

 xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var a=xmlhttp.readyState;


 document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Why it shows nothing when I open it?
If I download the link (as a .html file) into my computer, it works

Comment: This may cause because of same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy . Are you sure you make ajax call from same domain?

Answer (score 3):

You are, presumably, running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

JavaScript on a website can't make a browser get data from another website and expose it to the JavaScript on the first website.

Comment: I don't really think so.

If I change the link into this 

var link = "http://www.ubeauty.com.hk/apps/ios/article_content?id=1447"

It works again.

Comment: @LeoChan — So if you use `www.ubeautu.com.hk` it doesn't work but if you use `ubeautu.com.hk` then it does? You **are** hitting the same origin policy. (1) Use **relative** URIs. (2) Pick one of the two hostnames to be canonical and redirect from the other one to it (avoid having two URIs that point to the same content).

Comment: If I have hit the same origin policy, both
      var link = "http://www.utravel.com.hk/mobile-app/news-xml.php?id=3248";    and    var link = "ubeauty.com.hk/apps/ios/article_content?id=1447" should not work.

But now the latter works but the former one doesn't.

Comment: Your question says `http://www.utravel.com.hk/mobile-app/news-xml.php?id=3248` not `utravel.com.hk/mobile-app/news-xml.php?id=3248`.